# Hamiltonian reduction for unit sphere

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, representation-theory, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M, \omega)$, be Symplectic Vector space and $N\subset M$ be unit sphere. Then why $N/ker\omega\mid _N$ is naturally $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}(\mathbb{C})$

Here ker$\omega$=$\{ y\in M: \omega(x,y)=0,  \forall x\in M\}$

Comment: In what sense is $N$ a unit sphere if we have no metric? What exactly do you mean by $\ker(\omega)$ and $N/\ker(\omega)|_N$? Where does this question come from? Please provide all the relevant details when asking a question.

Comment: @HenryT.Horton: I think it should say $\mathrm{ker}(\omega|_N)$. I'm also a bit confused though; in particular, I see no Hamiltonian in this Hamiltonian reduction. h.jolany, perhaps you could provide a simple example of what you are looking for?

Comment: @fuglede ,$\frac{N}{ker(\omega)\mid N}$ means Hamiltonian reduction.

Comment: If you want to do Hamiltonian reduction, can you tell us what the group is, what the Hamiltonian group action is, what the moment map is, etc.? Also, the definition of $\ker(\omega)$ you've edited in makes no sense unless $M = \Bbb R^{2n}$, since $\omega$ takes tangent vectors as arguments, not points of the manifold.

Comment: Yes, you right, you mentioned to a good point, here I mean, $M$,  is symplectic vector space, and I made mistake.

Comment: In fact, when $N$ is pre-symplectic vector space then $N/ker\omega$ is called Hamiltonian reduction.